# How to post back to server after Single Page Application release/update

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

I have a SPA Angular website. Whenever we release a change to the website, the user's browser does not go back to the server to get the new javascript files. The app happily keeps running in the user's browser, and while it will make ajax calls for data, the javascript files do not change. This can cause errors if the signature of the back-end API being called changes, etc. If the user refreshes the page, they get the updated javascript files and everything works fine after that.

Is there a way to tell the browser that the site has been updated and to get the new javascript files, rather than just running the app with the same files?

I use the Angular CLI to build the application, so when the website is released, the javascript files have hashes at the end etc. This isn't an issue with files being cached and not updated... it's an issue with the browser knowing that it needs to request the files or refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to poll the server for changes and refresh the browser when changes are found.

An alternative to web workers is using [setInteterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) just refresh after a given time.

Yet another alternative is to have a version number in your API responses, and the JavaScript handlers would refresh the page when the version numbers are out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a program in your angular code that:

1. periodically checks the version of the api if changes where made
2. does the periodic check to ascertain when the user is idle AND when the user is not in a edit page with dirty fields.
3. refreshes the page when step 2 condition is met

use this library to watch idleness
https://github.com/shawnmclean/Idle.js

Answer (score 0):

If the file udated have the seame name add this text after the "?" like "?ver1.1" is suppose to tell the browser that there is a new version of the file.

you can use  manifest file
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/offline.html#manifests

another way is with

```
CacheStorage,clear()
```